# In Realm how can we search a list field and compare multiple field in the list

Tags: swift, realm

I have below schema

```
Product 
 - name
 - stocks (Linked List of Objects <Inventories>)

Inventories
- product (Product)
- stock = 0
- stores (Linked List of Objects <Store>)


Store
- code
- name
```

Now I want to filter Product where stock is greater than 0 in a store

For this I am using below filter in product. But it will show any product which have store with code dm1 and stock > 0 in any store.

```
ANY stocks.stores.code ==[c] \"dm1\" AND ANY stocks.stock > 0
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using Sub querying 
Like below

```
SUBQUERY(stocks, $inventory, $inventory.store.code ==[c] 'dm1' AND $inventory.stock > 0).@count > 0
```